# Solr filter query - not applied to multiple fields

Tags: solr, criteria

In solr dashboard I do a filter query and works fine.
-(status:PROCESS AND is_active: true)

I do want to build this same in Criteria query

Criteria criteria = new Criteria("status").is("PROCESS")
                    .and(new Criteria("is_active").is(true)).not();
The above statement doesn't gives me the expected result.

Please help me to solve this, thanks in advance

Comment: Turn up logging in Solr to `INFO` level (you can do this under `Logging` in the web interface). This should log all queries to Solr, and you can see exactly what query has been generated. It'd also be very helpful to know where this `Criteria` class is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria("status").is("PROCESS")
                    .and(new Criteria("is_active").is(true));
        return QUERY_PARSER.getQueryString(new SimpleQuery(criteria.notOperator()));
```

I solved with above piece of code. Thanks